# Retrieving Firebase value using `once` callback with transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I would like to use the `once` method to retrieve data from a Firebase ref, but am not receiving any data in the snapshot.
Here is the simple data retrieval:

**EDIT** After further inspection, I found that a transaction was being scheduled shortly after the `once` value listener. (For simplicity I will place the transaction *directly* after the listener for this code example.)

```
dataRef.once('value', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.val(); // returns `null`
});

dataRef.transaction(function (currentValue) {
  if (currentValue) {
    // make changes
  }
  return currentValue;
});
```

There is data at this firebase ref. To verify, I tried using `on` instead of `once`. In this case, the callback is invoked twice:

```
dataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.val(); // returns `null` first, then called again and returns correct value
});
```

What is causing this behavior? I would expect the snapshot to have the correct value the first time the callback is invoked. Otherwise, the `once` method has no useful purpose.

Comment: I've used `once` plenty of times to know that it **can** work. Most likely you're doing something different, which is unfortunately difficult to tell from just these code snippets. Can you provide a minimal reproduction of your problem either inside your question (click 'edit' and then 'code snippet') or on jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: I have also used once at least... err, once, with some success; a humble tens of thousands of developers and dozens of very prominent enterprise customers have done the same.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, you are right that there was something else going on. After much more digging and inspection, I found that a transaction was being scheduled shortly after the `once` value listener. I will update the original question to reflect the new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) for `transaction` there is a third argument `applyLocally`.

> By default, events are raised each time the transaction update function runs. So if it is run multiple times, you may see intermediate states. You can set this to false to suppress these intermediate states and instead wait until the transaction has completed before events are raised.

Because of this default value, the `once` value listener is firing after the transaction runs locally the first time, even though no data has been retrieved from the server (passing `null` as the transaction's `currentValue`). By passing `false` as the `applyLocally` parameter, this local event is suppressed, and the `once` callback will only be invoked after data has been retrieved from the server:

```
dataRef.transaction(function (currentValue) {
  if (currentValue) {
    // make changes
  }
  return currentValue;
},
function(){},
false);
```

Comment: Interesting corner case. Makes me once again glad that I don't use `once` very often. I recommend the use of `on` for most cases. When you use Firebase, you have to switch from "this is where I load my data" to a "my data is constantly synchronized and can thus appear at any time" mindset. You're *watching* a "living" data structure, not *loading* from a static one.

Comment: Yes, it is interesting, I'm glad there is an explanation for the behavior I was experiencing. Thanks for the tips.